# Join Threads java

Tags: java, multithreading, join

I have this code:

```
public final class Hello() {

    static long x1;
    static long x2;

    public static long start(args...) {
       //commands...
       Thread left = new Thread(){ 
           @Override
           public void run(){ 
               x1 = amethod(args...);   
           }
       }; 
       Thread right = new Thread(){ 
           @Override
           public void run(){ 
               x2 = amethod(args...);  
           }
       }; 
       left.start(); 
       right.start();
       x = x1 + x2;
   }
   return x;
}
```

Thread named `"left"` and thread named `"right"` are independent threads. My question is if x gets the correct value or the command `"x=x1+x2"` will executed before the threads ends.

I must use compulsorily `join()`?

Comment: Did you run your code for output?

Comment: Is this not what `Future`s were invented for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Thread named "left" and thread named "right" are independent threads. My question is if x gets the correct value or the command "x = x1 + x2" will executed before the threads ends. I must use compulsorily join()?

Yes you must call `join()`.  There is no guarantee that the 2 background threads will even be *started* before the main thread reaches the `x = x1 + x2` line let along finished.

In addition, whenever you are sharing data between two threads, you need to worry about memory synchronization between the threads as well.  When you join with a thread you are guaranteed to have all of the threads memory synchronized with the thread that calls `join()`.

So in the main thread you should do:

```
left.start(); 
right.start();
// left and right threads are running in the background...
// we join with them so we can make sure they have finished
// and we can sync with their memory updated of x1 and x2
left.join();
right.join();
x = x1 + x2;
```

Lastly, as an alternative, you can use an `ExecutorService` and a `Future<Integer>` which allow you to do something like:

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
// spawn our jobs into the pool
Future<Integer> future1 = threadPoll.submit(new Callable<Integer>() { ... });
Future<integer> future2 = threadPool.submit(new Callable<Integer>() { ... });
// once all jobs have been submitted you shutdown the pool
threadPool.shutdown();
// the get() methods here wait for the threads to finish and return a value
int x = future1.get() + future2.get();
```

The `ExecutorService` takes care of the thread spawning and the `Future` will return the value from the `call()` method.  Very useful.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that `x1` and `x2` will be set to the value you require by the time you add them together to get `x`.

The only way to guarantee this is with a call to `join()` on both threads.

Comment: Ok, this is what I wanted. Because many examples executing ,print correct result without the use of join()

Comment: Those are probably down to luck more than anything else.  If you appreciate this answer, please do not forget to upvote and accept.

Answer (score 0):

join() function makes sure that current thread will wait for calling thread to finish and only then the next statement would be executed. So,before adding up the values of x1 and x2, we must use the following,
left.join();
right.join();